# jQuery validate if at least 1 checked

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have this html piece of markup:

```
  <div class="isreq ">
    <div class="row gov_q">
      <div class="form-group">
        <div class="col-xs-8">
          <h5>I want to answer the questions about me.</h5>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-4 col-xs-12 label-right-align">
          <input id="extraquestionsgov" name='answer_extra_questions' value='Y' autocomplete="off" type="radio" {% if extraquestionsgov %}checked{% endif %}>
          <label for="extraquestionsgov" class="button-radius">YES</label>
          <input name="answer_extra_questions" id="extraquestionsgov2" value="N" autocomplete="off" type="radio" {% if extraquestionsgov2 %}checked{% endif %}>
          <label for="extraquestionsgov2" class="button-radius">NO</label>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <p class="err"></p>
  </div>


    <div class="isreq">
      <div class="row gov_q">
        <div class="form-group" id='eth_b1' name="eth_b1">
          <div class="col-sm-4 col-md-4" style="vertical-align: middle;">
            <h5>Your Ethnicity</h5>
          </div>
          <div class="col-sm-8 col-md-8 col-xs-12 label-right-align" style='padding:5px;'>
            <div id="ethb1" class="ethb1" name="ethb1">
            <input type="checkbox" name="eth" value="1" id="eth1_1" class='chk-btn'/>
            <label for='eth1_1'>&nbsp; Hispanic &nbsp;</label>
            <input type="checkbox" name="eth" value="2" id="eth2_1" class='chk-btn'/>
            <label for='eth2_1'> &nbsp;Non Hispanic&nbsp;</label>
            <input type="checkbox" name="eth" value="3" id="eth3_1" class='chk-btn'/>
            <label for='eth3_1'> &nbsp;Other &nbsp;</label>
            </div>

          </div>

        </div>
      </div>
      <p class="err "></p>
    </div>
```

and this jQuery code for validation:

```
   var $form1_validator = $('#wizard').validate({
    errorClass: 'error error-plugin label label-info',
    highlight: function(element, errorClass, validClass) {
        $(element).addClass('error error-plugin').removeClass(validClass);
    },
    unhighlight: function(element, errorClass, validClass) {
        $(element).removeClass('error error-plugin').addClass(validClass);
    },
    errorPlacement: function(err, element) {
        console.log(err);
        var el = element.parents('.isreq').find('.err');
        el.prepend(err);
    },
    rules: {
           answer_extra_questions: {
          required: true
        },

        eth: {
          minlength: 1,
          required: true, 
        },
};
```

WHY IT WORKS OF FOR THE answer_extra_questions BUT NOT !!! FOR eth ????
From the first view everything is the same, except radio button and checkboxes. Work good for radio button but don't work for the checkboxes.

Who has any suggestions?

Comment: You have an extra comma in the `eth` rule. Sometimes this can cause errors. Have you checked console to see if there are any js errors? If there are js error's reported by console please update your question to include them.

Comment: Checked - did not help

Comment: If this is exactly your code you should have syntax errors in console. Your last `}` here closes out the rules object and you don't close out your validate object. Fixing these and things work out. https://jsfiddle.net/538un1ay/1/ If you hit f12 you will open up your console and you can see your js errors.

Comment: No this is only a piece of code. in fact selection variants are much more

Comment: Your code sample has syntax errors and doesn't represent your actual problem. Fixing the syntax errors provides working code that doesn't represent your issue. If you want help in the future, I would suggest ensuring the code matches the errors you are seeing and do not provide a sample that is not representative of your issue.

Answer (score 0):

Change the name of your checkboxes to a name with `[]`:

**HTML:**

```
<label><input type="checkbox" name="eth[]" value="Hispanic" />Hispanic</label>
<label><input type="checkbox" name="eth[]" value="Non-Hispanic" />Non Hispanic</label>
<label><input type="checkbox" name="eth[]" value="Other" />Other</label>
```

**jQuery validate:**

```
// ...

rules:
{
   // Dont forget to add the ' '
   'eth[]':{ required:true, minlength:1 }
},
messages:
{
    'eth[]':
    {
        required:"Please select an ethnicity.<br/>"
    }
},

// ...
```

[**Here**](https://codepen.io/Ivan-86/pen/VyLrJo) is a working example.

Comment: radio button doesn't allow multiple selections. It is required here they can choose more than one value for eth.

Comment: NO changes, so checkbox is currently unguilty. "Who Framed Roger Rabbit  ?"

Comment: You need to add the `[]` for checkbox groups like `eth[]:` instead of `eth:`.

Comment: In this case I receive some error. square brackets block some other code and the whole script start to work incorrectly - only square brackets added.

Comment: I just got it working I will edit my original answer so we don't flood the page with irrelevant stuff.

Answer (score 0):

Problem fixed. Can not explain what caused this but such representation:

```
<input type="checkbox" name="eth" value="1" id="eth1_1" class='chk-btn'/>
<label for='eth1_1'>&nbsp; Hispanic &nbsp;</label>
```

caused the error .

My solution. I added an extra hidden input checkbox with no any specific decorations, but with the same name attribute. and with an empty value attribute.

```
<input name="eth" class='fix' type="checkbox" value="" id='eth1' >
```

class fix for CSS only, which was next:

```
.fix {
visibility: hidden;
z-index: -1;
position: absolute;
left: 0px;
```

}

And everything started to work.

Perhaps the whole problem was in my desire to make a checkbox look like a button (display:none) was there to hide the "check square" for a mark